# Get XML atribute using XSLT for a href on HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have come across this problem while doing a home project and I honestly do not know how to solve it.

The goal is, using XSLT, get a certain attribute from my XML and add it to **href**.

```
<Video videoID="v0001" imageLink="IMG/VIDEO_IMG/v0001_img.jpg"/>
```

Then, by applying the XSLT, that looks kinda like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Video"/>
    <a href="X">
        <img src="Y"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

where X is the imageLink from the XML and Y is gonna be the local link to the XHTML page of that single video.

```
<!--The goal is getting something like this after using XSLT-->
<a href="VIDEOS/video_v0001.xhtml">
    <img class="User" src="../IMG/VIDEO_IMG/v0001_img.png" alt="VideoImage"/>
</a>
```

Comment: The example does not disclose the logic which needs to be applied here.

Comment: Ok, Made some corrections, hope its helps understanding the problem better

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `imageLink` is `"IMG/VIDEO_IMG/v0001_img.jpg"` not `"VIDEOS/video_v0001.xhtml"`. And I have no idea what "local link" means.

Comment: Not to mention your xsl:for-each does nothing as it has no statements inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that your XML input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Videos>
  <Video videoID="v0001" imageLink="IMG/VIDEO_IMG/v0001_img.jpg"/>
  <Video videoID="v0002" imageLink="IMG/VIDEO_IMG/v0002_img.jpg"/>
</Videos>
```

Then the XSLT script performing your task can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xhtml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system= "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <xsl:for-each select="Videos/Video">
        <a href="VIDEOS/video_{@videoID}.xhtml">
          <img class="User" src="../{substring-before(@imageLink, '.')}.png"
            alt="VideoImage"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

As you can see, there should be 2 *Attribute Value Templates* (`{...}`),
one drawing the content from source `videoID` attribute and the other -
from `imageLink`.

In the second case the content to be copied is limited to the part
before the dot, because in this case file name extension is different.

Note that I used `method="xhtml"` and both `doctype` attributes for `XHTML`
page. Maybe in your case they should be different.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjVH/1

To get a full HTML page, add `<head>` tag and other HTML stuff, according
to your needs, e.g. a stylesheet for `User` class.